# Itextsharp Next line in paragraph coming right below serial number

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, itext

[image: Image from PDf]I am working on generating PDF using iTextSharp. I have some notes to be written on the page after giving a serial number. I am using `Paragraph`. But next line in paragraph comes right under serial number. How can I define margins or padding to paragraph only if it goes to next line?

My code

```
for(int i=0;i<list.count;i++)
{
    doc.Add(new Paragraph(String.Format("{0}) {1} ({2}).", (i + 1).ToString(), "Here Goes My String", "Date Time"), font));
}
```

`i` is the serial number.

Comment: Can you draw a simple image of what you're trying to do, its not quite clear from your description.

Comment: Hello @ChrisHaas I have uploaded image of part my pdf.Now next line in pdf comes right under serial number i.e 1 ,I want this line padded or want to specify margin so that it looks good

Answer (score 0):

Rather adding your list items to paragraph, create List items of itextsharp and add it to Arraylist of listItem. You can create Ordered and Unorder list item, similar to HTML counterpart `<ul>` and `<ol>`

Check below code:

```
  iTextSharp.text.List list = new iTextSharp.text.List(iTextSharp.text.List.ORDERED, 20f);
  list.IndentationLeft = 20f;//indented 20 points from left margin
  list.Add("The RomanList is added to the ordered list, and iTextSharp indents the RomanList relative to the ordered list to which it belongs");
  list.Add("The RomanList is added to the ordered list, and iTextSharp indents the RomanList relative to the ordered list to which it belongs");
  list.Add("Three");
  pdfDoc.Add(list);//add list to document
```

Above code will create ordered list. Second argument sets symbolIndent to 20 points, this results in to  the space between number and the item itself.

To know more about creating lists with Itextsharp, check out below link:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/83/Lists-with-iTextSharp