# continuing text to next page

Tags: java, itext

I want to generate a PDF of questions and their options using iText. I am able to generate the PDF but the problem is sometimes questions get printed at the end of a page and options go to the next page.

How can I determine that a question and its option will not fit in the same page?

This means that if question and options will not fit in the same page then that they must be placed on the next page.

**UPDATED**

```
com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(PageSize.A4,50,50,15,15);          
ByteArrayOutputStream OutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, OutputStream);
document.open();
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Paper Name Here",new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN,15,Font.BOLD));
paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
document.add(paragraph);
document.addTitle("Paper Name Here");       
document.addAuthor("corp");
com.itextpdf.text.List list = new com.itextpdf.text.List(true);

for (long i = 1; i <= 20 ; i++) 
{
    List<MultipleChoiceSingleCorrect> multipleChoiceSingleCorrects = new MultipleChoiceSingleCorrectServicesImpl().getItemDetailsByItemID(i);
    for (MultipleChoiceSingleCorrect multipleChoiceSingleCorrect : multipleChoiceSingleCorrects) {
        list.add(multipleChoiceSingleCorrect.getItemText());                    
        RomanList oplist = new RomanList();             
        oplist.setIndentationLeft(20);                      
        for (OptionSingleCorrect optionSingleCorrect : multipleChoiceSingleCorrect.getOptionList()) {
            oplist.add(optionSingleCorrect.getOptionText());
        }
        list.add(oplist);
    }
}        
document.add(list);
document.close();
```

after this I m getting abnormal page brakes means some times question is at end of page and option jumps to next page.(AS shown in image below)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are interested in are the `setKeepTogether(boolean)` methods :

- for [`Paragraph`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Paragraph.html#setKeepTogether%28boolean%29)
- or for [`PdfPTable`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#setKeepTogether%28boolean%29)

This will keep the object in one page, forcing the creation of a new page if the content doesn't fit in the remaining page.

Comment: I referred [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610483/itextsharp-next-line-in-paragraph-coming-right-below-serial-number) and created the list. first list will hold question and another list will hold its option. I updated code in question. as u said `setKeepTogether(boolean)` applicable to Paragraph n PdfPtable now how can I apply to list.

Comment: Either add that list to a `Paragraph` or to a `PdfPCell` (inside an `PdfPTable`), and you're done!

Comment: `@Alexis Pigeon` I tried a lot of adding list to paragraph or pdftable. problem with adding list in paragraph is, In list I may have numbers of questions with its option so if I add all list in paragraph then generated PDF having some blank pages, and if I make list of one question and its option then number to question is always "1" as list get reset. Can you help me more?

Comment: For each question, add to your main list a `Paragraph` with `setKeepTogether(true)` that will contain both `multipleChoiceSingleCorrect.getItemText()`, a new line, and the `oplist`. That should do the trick.

Comment: `@Alexis Pigron` as you said I developed the code, added as answer. this solves question splitting problem but why I m not getting list number. I set list as numbered `com.itextpdf.text.List list = new com.itextpdf.text.List(true);` where I m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

with the help of [`Alexis Pigeon`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065525/alexis-pigeon) I done with this code. So special thanks to him.

I have added question text to `Paragraph` after that all options kept in an list.
Option list `opList` added in `paragraph`, this `paragraph` add to an `ListItem` and this `ListItem`
added to an master `list`.

This way question splitting on two pages is resolved but I m not getting question numbers.. I already set master list as numbered=true `com.itextpdf.text.List list = new com.itextpdf.text.List(true);`

Code:-

```
    try {
        String Filename="PaperName.pdf";
        com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(PageSize.A4,50,50,15,15);          
        ByteArrayOutputStream OutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, OutputStream);           
        document.open();
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Paper Name Here",new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN,15,Font.BOLD));
        paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);           
        paragraph.setSpacingAfter(20);      
        document.add(paragraph);
        document.addTitle("Paper Name Here");       
        document.addAuthor("crop");
        document.addCreator("crop");
        com.itextpdf.text.List list = new com.itextpdf.text.List(true);
        for (long i = 1; i <= 20 ; i++) 
        {
            List<MultipleChoiceSingleCorrect> multipleChoiceSingleCorrects = new MultipleChoiceSingleCorrectServicesImpl().getItemDetailsByItemID(i);
            for (MultipleChoiceSingleCorrect multipleChoiceSingleCorrect : multipleChoiceSingleCorrects) {
                Paragraph paragraph2 =new Paragraph();
                paragraph2.setKeepTogether(true);
                paragraph2.add(multipleChoiceSingleCorrect.getItemText());
                paragraph2.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                RomanList oplist = new RomanList();             
                oplist.setIndentationLeft(20);                      
                for (OptionSingleCorrect optionSingleCorrect : multipleChoiceSingleCorrect.getOptionList()) {                       
                    oplist.add(optionSingleCorrect.getOptionText());
                }
                paragraph2.add(oplist); 
                paragraph2.setSpacingBefore(20);                    
                ListItem listItem =new ListItem();
                listItem.setKeepTogether(true);
                listItem.add(paragraph2);
                list.add(listItem);
            }
        }
        document.add(list);
        document.close();
        response.setContentLength(OutputStream.size());
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Filename);
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        OutputStream.writeTo(out);
        out.flush();
        } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you create a `ListItem`? Why not using `list.add(paragraph2)` directly?

Comment: @AlexisPigeon previously I did the same. if I directly use list.add(paragraph2); then generated pdf having blank page only no questions n options get rendered. as list.add() return true if adding operation is successful; otherwise false so I checked with sysout(list.add(paragraph2)) it gives me false. so that I just tried with ListItem then all question n options get printed only list number is not getting print.